# Marshal float* to C#

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, dll, marshalling

I have a DLL which exports a function that returns a float*, that I would like to use it in my C# code. I am not sure how to Marshal my float* so that I can safely use it in C#.
So, in my C++ DLL, I have declared:

```
static float* GetSamples(int identifier, int dataSize);
```

In my C# script, I have:

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
public static extern float[] GetSamples (int identifier, int dataSize);
```

The C++ GetSamples(int,int) allocates memory and return a pointer t the float array. How do I declare the C# GetSamples to Marshal my float array, and how do I access the data (either by iteration or Marshal.Copy)?
Also, can I delete the float* from C# or do I have to call another C++ function to delete the allocated memory?

EDIT:
So this is what I have tried up to now.
First, on the C# side:

Declaration:

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
public static extern int GetSamples ([In, Out]IntPtr buffer,int length, [Out] out IntPtr written);
```

Trying to call it:

```
IntPtr dataPointer = new IntPtr();
IntPtr outPtr;
GetSamples(dataPointer, data.Length, out outPtr);
for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++){
    copiedData[i] = Marshal.ReadByte(dataPointer, i);
}
```

Then in my C++ lib:

```
int AudioReader::RetrieveSamples(float * sampleBuffer, size_t dataLength, size_t * /* out */ written)
{
    float* mydata = new float[dataLength];

    //This is where I copy the actual data into mydata

    memcpy(sampleBuffer, mydata, dataLength*sizeof(float));

    delete data;
    return dataLength;
}
```

I don't really know what outPtr is for... And I know I have some additional copying steps that I can removes, I just want to get it working for now.

Comment: Do you control the code of that DLL?

Comment: yes I do control the code of the DLL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is a bit of a complicated answer...

.NET doesn't know how to handle C++ memory allocation, so regardless returning a `float *` is dangerous at best for this. Furthermore the .NET memory model is based on COM so it is `CoTaskMemAlloc` based, not that it really helps you here. So here is what I would suggest:

```
int AudioReader::RetrieveSamples(
     float * sampleBuffer,
     int dataLength,
     int * /* out */ written)
{
     // assuming mydata is already defined
     if(sampleBuffer == NULL || dataLength == 0)
     {
         *written = sizeof(mydata);
         return -1;
     }
     ZeroMemory(sampleBuffer, dataLength);
     int toCopy = min(dataLength, sizeof(myData));
     //This is where I copy the actual data into mydata

     memcpy(sampleBuffer, mydata, toCopy);
     *written = toCopy;
     return 0;
 }
```

```
 [DLLImport("__internal")]
 private static extern int GetSamples(
     [In, Out]IntPtr buffer,
     [In] int length,
     [Out] out int written);

 float[] RetrieveFloats()
 {
     int bytesToAllocate = 0;
     GetSamples(IntPtr.Zero, 0, out bytesToAllocate);
     if(bytesToAllocate == 0)
        return null;
     int floatCount = bytesToAllocate/ sizeof(float);
     float[] toReturn = new float[floatCount];
     IntPtr allocatedMemory = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytesToAllocate);

     int written = 0;
     if(GetSamples(allocatedMemory, bytesToAllocate, out written) != -1)
     {
         floatCount = written/sizeof(float);
         Marshal.Copy(allocatedMemory, toReturn, 0, floatCount);
     }
     Marshal.FreeHGlobal(allocatedMemory);
     return toReturn;
 }
```

Passing a bufferLength of zero would return the space required for the buffer, which can then be allocated and passed in.

You will need to allocate the memory for the buffer in C#, you cannot allocate it in C++

Comment: What does written do? I tried implementing this, I am still having trouble. I declare an IntPtr that I pass as sampleBuffer, and use memcpy in C++ to assign some data to it -> memcpy(sampleBuffer, mydata, bufferLength*sizeof(float));, then on the C# side, I try and read it using Marshal.ReadByte(dataPointer, i);, but I get a bad access error. I am a newbie when it comes to this, any tips? I will update my question with more details.

Comment: the IntPtr holds a reference to a C# array that you'll allocate, in and of itself it's just a pointer holder. You'll call the pinvoke twice, once to get the size of array to allocate (written can be an int and not an intptr if you'll never allocate that much memory, but if you change written in C# change it to an int in C++ too), the size to allocate will be returned in written. The second call will be with the array assigned to the buffer intptr, the length assigned to the length intptr

Comment: @DavidMenard I've edited my sample to be easier to use, but a reminder you do need to do the memory allocation in C# not C++

Comment: So I'm still having trouble calling the method. Problem is that I'm in Unity3d and I can't use "unsafe", so I can't use IntPtr.ToPointer(). Declaring new float[dataLen]; on the C# side and passing it as a float* to C++ doesn't work either.

Comment: @DavidMenard Updated my example to do it the hard way. You should never need to use `unsafe` in C#.

Comment: Ended up using marshalling: [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] float[] buffer. Easy stuff ;) Thanks for all the help Mgetz! Very appreciated

Comment: It's not a good idea to reuse the same function for two purposes. Better use another function to get the wanted buffer size (for example `C++: int getSampleSize();`). The code would also get much better to read.